# Error with Oracle data access reference in a C# windows application

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm beginner in C# and Oracle database programming.  I want to write simple windows application to connect to an Oracle database.  I use `Orcale.DataAccess ver 2.0` but when I run my program I get this error:

[image: error]

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Show your work and exception as a text, not image.

Comment: Did you copy Oracle.DataAccess.dll to your bin folder or using GAC reference?

Comment: @SonerGönül thanks my friend,but i want show all event accord in my vs.

Comment: @KemalKefeli i use add reference in vs and add that dll to my project and i see that file in reference in solution explorer

Comment: This exception is mostly related to x64 vs x86 issues. Consider installing both clients as suggested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24120100/5280641).

Comment: So, maybe there is a problem with your Oracle Client or ODAC installation. I have a long shot suggestion, build your solution, go to your project's bin directory, delete Oracle.DataAccess.dll and then run exe file.